# Helm not considering my remote repo

Tags: kubernetes, nexus, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm 2.6.1 to deploy a package to my kubernetes cluster. I have created a nexus raw repository to host the packaged helm charts. I also have the index file uploaded to the same.

```
--charts
 - wordpress-0.1.0.tgz
 - index.yaml
```

However, when I try to do a helm install, it never finds the package. I have tried all the below ways. Any other options to try?

```
+ helm repo list
  NAME      URL                                                                          
  stable    https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com                             
  local     http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts                                                 
  helm-repo https://admin:admin@nexus.hosted.com/repository/kubecharts/charts

+ helm repo update

Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "helm-repo" chart repository
...Unable to get an update from the "stable" chart repository 
(https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com):
Get https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: dial tcp: 
lookup kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com on 10.00.0.00:53: no such 
host
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 

+ helm search wordpress-0.1.0.tgz
  WARNING: Repo "stable" is corrupt or missing. Try 'helm repo update'.No 
  results found

+ helm search helm-repo/wordpress-0.1.0.tgz
  WARNING: Repo "stable" is corrupt or missing. Try 'helm repo update'.No 
  results found

 + helm install helm-repo/wordpress-0.1.0.tgz
   Error: file "helm-repo/wordpress-0.1.0.tgz" not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You references the chart wrong way. Try 

`helm search helm-repo/wordpress
helm install helm-repo/wordpress`

If you need to install particular version:

`helm install helm-repo/wordpress --version=0.1.0`

Comment: admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog$ helm search helm-repo/prometheus
No results found

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit preemptive, but in a few days I should be releasing a helm-hosted plugin at: https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-helm

You can likely use this instead of raw moving forward. I'd watch the repo, etc... it should be coming out this week or early next week.

Using raw is neat, but this should start creating the index.yaml for you moving forward, etc...